# .Net : Do I need to create a Custom Control in a different Project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, user-controls

this question may be asked, but I am wanting to create Custom Controls, and for some reason, every tutorial online says we should create a special project and then reference the dll into the mother project.

Do we really need to do it like that? I'm trying to use ClickOnce and its simpler to deploy when its only one Project.

I want to know, is it necesary to do it like that, and if not can I just create a CustomControl o UserControl and have that called??

Comment: No you don't need a separate assembly.

Comment: `I'm trying to use ClickOnce and its simpler to deploy when its only one Project` - Not true. ClickOnce is not "simpler" if you have 1 project versus multiple projects. It's the same. And also, having different projects for different "layers" of the application is the correct way.

Comment: HighCore, ClickOnce is a simple "click" when its one project. When you add multiple projects under a solucion, the soluction itself can't be deployed underclick once unless you fiddle around with the macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not *necessary* but *recommended* to define your custom control in a separate class library project, so reusing it is as easy as making a reference to that project.

Comment: So basically its not necessary and I can still reuse the same control if its in the same project. Ok thanks.